# Product rule in fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I have to prove the following inequality
$$\Vert fg\Vert_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq C \Vert f\Vert_{H^\sigma(\mathbb{R}^3)}\Vert g\Vert_{H^{s+1}(\mathbb{R}^3)}$$
with $s\geq 0$, $\sigma\geq\max\{\frac{1}{2},s\}$ and $(s,\sigma)\neq (\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$.

I've tried to use the following generalization of Leibnitz rule but without success
$$\Vert J^s(fg)\Vert_p\leq \Vert J^{s+a}(f)\Vert_{p_1}\Vert J^{-a}(g)\Vert_{q_1}+\Vert J^{-b}f\Vert_{p_2}\Vert J^{s+b}(g)\Vert_{q_2}$$
where $J^s=(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{p_i}+\frac{1}{q_i}$ and $s,a,b\geq 0$.
Any help?

Comment: Have you tried by proving via definition of Sobolev space?

Comment: @Fundamental: I disagree. The critical regularity would be $3/2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, while the stated inequality holds for $s \geq 0$.

Comment: Retracted close vote.

Comment: Roughly speaking it almost works. Take $p_1 = 2 = q_2$ and $p_2 =q_1 = \infty$, with $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, you see that up to the fact that the Sobolev embedding $H^{3/2} \to L^\infty$ is not quite true you are gold. So instead you play with slightly different value of $p_2, q_2, b$ to avoid the log loss in the $L^\infty$ embedding, and you should be good; especially since the inequality has the right scaling.